# How do I get the name and email address of the selected checkbox in recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

This class adds all the users from the firebase database to the recyclerview. I want to add name and email addresses of the selected checkboxes in the recyclerview and then add them to a list

```
package com.tml.sharethem.demo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class AddMembers extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView txtGroup;
    private EditText mSearchField;
    private ImageButton mSearchBtn;
    private RecyclerView mResultList;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_members);
        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("group_name1");

        txtGroup= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
        txtGroup.setText("Select Members for "+data+"Group");

        mSearchField= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
        mResultList= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result__list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mUserDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(Users.class
                    ,R.layout.list_layout,
                    UsersViewHolder.class,
                    mUserDatabase) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {


                    viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getEmail());

                }


            };
            mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String searchText=mSearchField.getText().toString();
                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
            }
        });
    }

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
        Toast.makeText(AddMembers.this,"Search Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Query firebaseSearchQuery=mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText+"\uf8ff");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter1=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(Users.class
                ,R.layout.list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {


                viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getEmail());

            }
        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter1);
    }

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;
        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }

        TextView user_name;
        TextView user_email;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        public void setDetails(String userName,String userEmail)
        {

            user_name=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            user_email=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.email_text);
            checkBox= (CheckBox) mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


            user_name.setText(userName);
            user_email.setText(userEmail);
            boolean checked=checkBox.isChecked();


        }

    }

}
```

This is the model class of the recyclerview
Users.java

```
package com.tml.sharethem.demo;

/**
 * Created by SONI on 01/01/2018.
 */

public class Users {
    String name,email;
    private boolean isSelected;
    public Users(){

    }
    public Users(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Users(String name, String email, boolean isSelected) {

        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

This is the xml code for the main recyclerview.
addmembers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    tools:context="com.tml.sharethem.demo.AddMembers">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/txtGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Search Here..."/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_field"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/result__list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_members"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Add Selected Members" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement onCheckChangedListener

One way of doing is

Do the following  Modification in

```
 viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getEmail());
```

Change to

```
viewHolder.setDetails(Users model);
```

And do the following modification in setDetails()

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
               if(isChecked) {
                //Store in hashmap
                 hashmap.put(Users.userId,model)
                }else {
                  if(hashMap.containsKey(model.userId)) {   
                      hashMap.remove(model.userId)
             }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> You can use the ArrayList to store id of that particular record, for example, contact id,
> then on the click of any control you can retrieve the ids from ArrayList.
> ```

```
public static List<Integer> SelectedCheckbox = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

> inside recycler view, on checkbox click add or remove values from
>   arraylist

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
myCheckBoxContactItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // set tag inside onBindViewHolder method
                    int contactId = (int) mConvertView.getTag(R.string.contact_id);

                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked() && !SelectedContact.contains(contactId)) {
                                SelectedContact.add(contactId);
                            } else if (CommonUtils.SelectedContact.contains(contactId)) {
                                int indexOf = CommonUtils.SelectedContact.indexOf(contactId);
                                SelectedContact.remove(indexOf);
                            }
                    }
}

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    for(int i = 0; i< SelectedCheckbox.size; i++)
    {
        int contactId = SelectedCheckbox.get(i);
        // your database query to get record of particular id.
    }

}
```